# Picasso Android memory issues, when fragment is replaced

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, picasso

I'm building an android app with tab navigation.
Each tab has its own back stack and piles the fragment into back stack as the user navigates through application.

The problem is that when I navigate between fragments (using replace method of `FragmentTransaction`), the `imageView` into which images are loaded with Picasso also retain its state. And this results in OOM error eventually.

I want to free the memory for images when a fragment is replaced and recover the states when revisited. I'm considering following ways to solve this problem.

1. Free the memory used for adapters(`ListAdapter`, `FragmentAdapter`, ...)
   (Most of the images are presentation of an item in these adapters)
2. Call `adapter.clear()` to clear the content of the fragments.
3. Clear only `ImageViews`' content (if possible ..)

I'm not even sure among them exists the right way to implement the features.
What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Just a warning: If you're targeting Android 4.x, your approach might not be sufficient. Android 4.x has serious issues with images. It is basically unable to free up the associated memory until you end the activity, which doesn't seem to happen ever in you app. The only library that addresses the problem is [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/). However, it is more invasive than Picasso.

Comment: Facing the same problem, have you got any solution? Very interesting to know!

Answer (score 1):

**Hi, I had same:** UI on fragments with `.replace()` method, `Picasso` and memory leaks!
Simply replacing `Picasso` with `Glide` reduced my app’s memory leaks by more than 90%.

[Glide on Github](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Compared: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

You can pass fragments to Glide instead of Context - Glide knows how to deal with fragments' lifecycle. Also, please avoid creating Activity variables in your classes - references to activites are very likely to create leaks - better pass activity or context as parameter to every method that requires it.

Preventing memory leaks in android (From the Google-engeneer): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk
Hope it helps!